# Find the functions whose length is proportional to the area below them

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this problem:

"Find all the functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$, $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that the area below $f$ in $[a,b]$ is proportional to the length of the graphic of $f$ in that interval"

This is my progress:

I translate the problem into the following equality (taking in account the formula for the length of a function):

$$\int_a^b{f(x)}\mathrm{d}x =  K \int_a^b\sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2}\mathrm{d}x$$

We take $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}b}$ in both sides and using the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$f(b) = K \sqrt{1 + f'(b)^2}$$

From this last equality, I can see that the solution is going to be the hyperbolic cosine. But I would like to solve it more formally. Also, I think I have not took in account that the $f$ I am looking for is positive.

Comment: Will need some modification, the problem says *proportional*, so you will want arc length is a constant times the area.

Comment: You are right. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to start by noting that for any $x$ in the interval, we have
$$\int_a^x f(t)\,dt=K\int_a^x \sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2},dt.$$
Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we see that
$$f(x)=K\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}.$$
Write $y$ for $f(x)$. We get 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm\sqrt{y^2-K^2}.$$
We have obtained two closely related separable differential equations. For definiteness pick the first one, rewrite it as 
$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^2-K^2}}=dx$$
and integrate. To do the integration on the left, make the substitution  $y=K\cosh w$, or, less attractively, $y=K\sec w$.
 .

Comment: Thanks. Is it important that f is positive in any step?

Comment: The function $f$ must not change sign, and so if the constant of proportionality is postive, $f$ must also be.  This is because by the nature of arclength, it is **increasing**. If $f$ becomes negative anywherem, the integral starts to decrease.

Comment: How can I solve $K cosh(w) = y$ for w?

Comment: By definition of cosh we have $\frac{K}{2}(e^w+e^{-w})=y$. Multiply by $2e^w$, rearrange. We get $Ke^{2w}-2ye^w+K=0$. This is a quadratic equation in $e^w$. Solve for $e^w$ using quadratic formula, take the log to extract $w$. Idea is used several places, worth knowing.